# Why do I use softInputMode and don't return to the original position when the keyboard disappears?

Tags: android

I am adding my input box interface to WindowManager.I have added `softInputMode` in my `LayoutParams`. When I focus on `EditText`, the keyboard will jump out and I can achieve the effect I want!.But when the keyboard disappears, my layout does not return to the original position.

In the Android 7.0 interface can return to the original state, but will stop in Android 6.0

[In Android 7.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgRFu.gif)
[In Android 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYsj2.gif)

I am using a program to create a layout.
Here is my code.

```
public class TestCreateViewActivity extends BaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.btn_show) Button mBtnShow;

private WindowManager mManager;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParamsContent;
private int mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight;
private FrameLayout mContent;
private int mOffsetHeight, mTopHeight, mBottomHeight;

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
@Override
protected void initial(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    initWindow();
    initializeContent();

    onClicks(mBtnShow).subscribe(v -> mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mManager.removeView(mContent);
}

@Override
protected int onResource() {
    return R.layout.activity_test_create_view;
}


private void initWindow() {
    mManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    if (mManager != null) {
        Display display = mManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        mScreenWidth = size.x;
        mScreenHeight = size.y;
    }

    mOffsetHeight = (int) (mScreenHeight / 6.5) + ViewTools.getStatusBarHeight(mContext);

    mTopHeight = (mScreenHeight - mOffsetHeight) / 7;
    mBottomHeight = mScreenHeight - mOffsetHeight - mTopHeight;


    mParamsContent = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mParamsContent.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mParamsContent.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mParamsContent.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    } else {
        mParamsContent.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
    }

    mParamsContent.flags =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    mParamsContent.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    mParamsContent.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;

    mParamsContent.width = mScreenWidth;
    mParamsContent.height = mScreenHeight;
    mParamsContent.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}

@SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "RtlHardcoded", "CheckResult"})
private void initializeContent() {
    mContent = new FrameLayout(mContext);

    mContent.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mManager.addView(mContent, mParamsContent);

    OverLayContent overLayContent = new OverLayContent(mContext);
    mContent.addView(overLayContent.getView());
}

public class OverLayContent {

    private Context mContext;
    private View mView;
    private LinearLayout mLin;

    public OverLayContent(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        mLin = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        mLin.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mLin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        View empthView = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        empthView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mOffsetHeight));
        empthView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.overlay_top_style);
        mLin.addView(empthView);

        LinearLayout flMain = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        flMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        flMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        flMain.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mTopHeight + mBottomHeight));
        flMain.addView(createTopView());
        flMain.addView(createBottomView());

        mLin.addView(flMain);

        mView = mLin;
    }

    private View createTopView() {
        LinearLayout topView = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        topView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        topView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mTopHeight));
        topView.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.overlay_circle, null);
        view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, mTopHeight));
        view.setMinimumWidth(mTopHeight);

        topView.addView(view);

        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight = 1;
        return topView;
    }

    private View createBottomView() {
        FrameLayout bottomView = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        bottomView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mBottomHeight));

        LinearLayout linearLayout_main = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        linearLayout_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linearLayout_edit = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_edit = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_edit.weight = 1;
        linearLayout_edit.setLayoutParams(params_edit);
        linearLayout_edit.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_text = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_text.weight = 1;
        textView.setLayoutParams(params_text);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("Input");
        EditText editText = new EditText(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_editText = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_editText.weight = 1;
        editText.setLayoutParams(params_editText);
        linearLayout_edit.addView(textView);
        linearLayout_edit.addView(editText);
        linearLayout_main.addView(linearLayout_edit);

        LinearLayout linearLayout_button = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_button = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_button.weight = 1;
        linearLayout_button.setLayoutParams(params_button);
        linearLayout_button.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        Button button_left = new Button(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_left = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_left.weight = 1;
        button_left.setLayoutParams(params_left);
        button_left.setText("Back");
        linearLayout_button.addView(button_left);
        Button button_right = new Button(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_right = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params_right.weight = 1;
        button_right.setLayoutParams(params_right);
        button_right.setText("Back");
        linearLayout_button.addView(button_right);
        linearLayout_main.addView(linearLayout_button);

        bottomView.addView(linearLayout_main);
        return bottomView;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return mView;
    }
}
```

}

Is there anything I missed or is it wrong?

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: @user1506104 I am using a program to write layout, I have modified my question.